# What is the smallest variety of algebras containing all fields?

Tags: universal-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids, ra.rings-and-algebras

A field is a ring whose nonzero elements form a commutative group under multiplication. A field is also a commutative [inverse semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup) with respect to multiplication. The unique multiplicative inverse $y$ of an element $x$ (in the sense that $xyx=x$ and $yxy=y$) is $y=x^{-1}$ if $x \neq 0$ and $y=0$ if $x = 0$.

To simplify the discussion, define an *inverse ring* to be a ring which is an inverse semigroup with respect to multiplication. Denote the multiplicative inverse operation by $()^{-1}$. (Warning: The notion of an *inverse ring* doesn't exist outside of this question.) Both rings and *inverse rings* form a [variety of algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_%28universal_algebra%29), i.e. they can be defined by a set of operations ($+$, $*$, $-()$, $()^{-1}$, $0$, $1$ in this case) together with set of identities satisfied by these operations. I think that the commutative *inverse rings* are the smallest variety of algebras containing all fields.

**Question**

> A direct product of a family of fields is no longer a field. However, it is still a commutative *inverse ring*. My question is whether every commutative *inverse ring* is a [subdirect product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdirect_product) of a family of fields.

(Note that *subdirect product* here must refer to either rings or *inverse rings*, because the notion of *subalgebra* isn't defined otherwise. The answer to my question should be independent of which one we choose, but referring to *inverse rings* would make more sense to me.)

**Note** This question is identical to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120735/12490) at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you give an example for your notion. For example, in a direct product, what is the multiplicative inverse of $(0,1)$ ? 

Comment: @Ralph The multiplicative inverse of $(0,1)$ is $(0,1)$. Each idempotent element is its own inverse.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, your answer is 'yes' : Let $M(A)$ be the set of maximal ideal of your commutative inverse ring $A$. Then you have a map :

$$A \rightarrow \prod_{\rho \in M(A) } A / \rho $$.

Each projection is surjective. the kernel of this map si the jacobson radical $R$ of $A$

so let $x$ be in $R$ then $(1-xy)$ is invertible for all in $y$, in particular for $y$ the multiplicative inverse of $x$. but as $y(1-xy) =0$, then automaticaly $y=0$, and hence $x=0$.

So the previous map is injective, and $A$ is a subdirect product.

Answer (score 4):

Commutative inverse semigroups are examples of completely regular semigroups, that is, semigroups where each element belongs to a subsemigroup which is a group. It is an old result that any ring whose multiplicative reduct is completely regular is a subdirect product of division rings. I don't have the reference off hand, but I can find it. <strike>Basically one shows the Jacobson radical is trivial and then one observes that a primitive ring which is completely regular must be a division ring. A key step is to show the idempotents are central and so you have a possibly noncommutative inverse ring.</strike>

**Added.** I haven't quite found the old reference yet, but here is the proof. If R is a ring whose multiplicative reduct is completely regular, then it is von Neumann regularb and so its Jacobson radical is trivial. Thus it suffices to handle the primitive case, so assume R has a faithful simple module.  Clearly 1 and 0 are then the only central idempotents of R. Now we show all idempotents of R are central. By Clifford's structure theorem for completely regular semigroups, R is a semilattice of completely simple semigroups. So it suffices to show these completely simple semigroups are groups and then R will be an inverse semigroup with central idempotents. For this it suffices to show $\mathcal R$-equivalent and $\mathcal L$-equivalent idempotents e,f are equal. By symmetry we assume eR=fR. Then $(e-f)^2=0$ and hence e-f=0 since R is completely regular.

Thus R is a completely regular inverse monoid whose only idempotents are 0,1 and so R-{0} is a group, i.e., R is a division ring.

I believe the old paper I can't find shows a ring R is completely regular iff it is what ring theorists call strongly regular.

Comment: It's good to know that this is a special case of an old result. It's also uplifting that completely regular multiplicative semigroups of rings turn out to be Clifford semigroups. (I really like Clifford semigroups, because of $ab=ba \Leftrightarrow a^{-1}b=ba^{-1}$.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a notion of [von Neumann regular rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring). For commutative rings $A$, this notion has many equivalent definitions (for proofs see David F. Anderson, *Zero-Dimensional Commutative Rings*):

1) $A$ is zero-dimensional and reduced.

2) Every localization of $A$ is a field.

3) For every $x \in A$ we have $x^2 | x$.

4) For every $x \in A$ there is a unique $y \in A$ with $x = x^2 y$ and $y = y^2 x$; this $y$ is called the weak inverse of $x$.

So this is what you have called an inverse ring. The resulting variety is the smallest one containing all fields, since every reduced ring embeds into a product of fields.

Comment: Condition 4 in the non-commutative case is called strong regular. See my answer above. 

Comment: In a von Neumann regular ring, every element has at least one inverse, but the inverse elements are not unique, so the multiplicative inverse operation is not part of the definition. A strongly von Neumann regular ring is also an inverse ring (as I learned from the answer by Benjamin Steinberg), so one can define a multiplicative inverse operation there. That operation is important, because the resulting variety of algebras depends on the defined operations. ($\mathbb Z$ is a subalgebra of $\mathbb Q$ in the context of rings, but not in the context of inverse rings.)

Comment: Are you saying that 4) is not equivalent to being von Neumann regular? For commutative rings (and I only speak about commutative rings) I am pretty sure that the weak inverses *are* unique. $\mathbb{Z}$ is not von Neumann regular.

Comment: All I'm saying is that a multiplicative inverse operation is (implicitly) defined for a strongly von Neumann regular ring, but is not part of the definition of a von Neumann regular ring (and I tried to explain why). So defining "inverse rings" was easier than trying to work with "regular von Neumann rings". The wiki page tries to circumvent the issue by stating: "A commutative von Neumann regular ring $R$ is a subring of a product of fields closed under taking weak inverses". This is awkward, because of "...closed under...". Also, "subring of a product" is weaker than "subdirect product".

Comment: To clarify, what I'm trying to explain is that the statement: "So this is what you have called an inverse ring. The resulting variety is the smallest one containing all fields, since every reduced ring embeds into a product of fields." is incorrect in a subtle way. I introduced "inverse rings", because I needed a context where a multiplicative inverse operation is part of the definition of the algebra. In the context of rings, the variety of algebras containing all fields is larger, for example it contains $\mathbb Z$ (which I also tried to explain).

Comment: Just to mention, the inverse is unique in a von Neumann regular ring iff the idempotents commute, which is always the case for a commutative ring.  But of course for the universal algebra viewpoint one needs to decide which operations one allows.